# jQuery live/delegate/on vs. re-registering event handlers - which is better for AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

What's the best way to handle binding events on elements that will be refreshed with AJAX?

Is it better to use `$(selector).live` or similar methods for delegating events (`on` and `delegate`), or is it better to just re-bind the event handlers in `$.ajax` callbacks or `$(document).ajaxComplete` instead?

For the simple case, `$(selector).live` or equivalent works great, and seems like the right answer.

The tricky part is what to do inside a custom plug-in, where I'm creating a whole bunch of event handlers.  I start running into problems in more complex cases where I want to register a handler on some other element that affects the one referenced by `this`.

For example, see jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f6QSY/2/

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    $input = this;
    var origSelector = this.selector;

    $(document).on("click", "a#trigger1", function() {
        $input.val('set from trigger 1');
    });
    $(document).on("click", "a#trigger2", function() {
        $(origSelector).val('set from trigger 2');
    });
}

$("input#newInput").myPlugin();
$("#wrapper").append("<input type='text' id='newInput'>");

<div id="wrapper">
  <a href="#" id="trigger1">Trigger 1</a>
  <a href="#" id="trigger2">Trigger 2</a>
</div>
```

In this code, the plugin is called on an input that is added dynamically and doesn't exist yet (or is replaced via AJAX).  The plugin sets up listeners on different elements that then impact the value of the input.

The `trigger1` link doesn't work because `$input` refers to a jQuery object with a selector that returned no elements at the time it was bound.  The `trigger2` link does work, by backing out the original selector for the input with `this.selector` and creating a new, fresh jQuery object in the event listener.

Is this approach of backing out the selector safe, or should I just call myPlugin again after updating the DOM?

My back-end is Java/JSF/PrimeFaces although that doesn't matter too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Better" is a loaded qualifier. Better in terms of what?

I will always choose delegation (using `.on()`)... where the listener is the nearest non-destroyed/replaced ancestor of any Ajax elements that need event binding.

It's possibly not ALWAYS going to be the most efficient in terms of computational cycles... a lot depends on the structure of your page and just how close that ancestor is. But it's way way simpler to manage and decouples your Ajax call from your event binding.

To me, that's "better".

Sometimes what's needed is not a direct answer to "how can I get my approach to work" but rather, a suggestion on how to tweak or retool your approach. In this case, I think caching a string of this.selector is creating a tight coupling where there doesn't need to be one. Use classes, take advantage of DOM traversal (instead of IDs), and you will have a more re-usable product!

[update follows]

Not knowing exactly what your end goal is, here's a pretty faked-up example of how I approach this sort of binding.

Full Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QpXpD/2/

Reduced sample HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="foo clickable">
    <p>This is foo0.</p>
    <p class="info">Some info</p>
  </div>
  <div class="foo clickable">
    <p>This is foo1.</p>
    <p class="info">Some info</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.highlight { background-color: yellow; }
.info { display: none }
```

Reduced sample JS:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    this.on('click', '.clickable', function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('highlight');
        $this.find('.info').slideToggle();
    });
}

$('#wrapper').myPlugin();
```

The plugin executes on an element which is an ancestor element that I will never destroy and which is expected to contain my clickable elements.

In the sample, the plugin is set to listen on `#wrapper` for any clicks on any element that has the `clickable` class. Now it doesn't matter if I remove anything from the DOM or add new elements to that listening container... if I click and the element has the class `clickable` the function will execute. I do the `find()` in the context of the click, not the context of the full document or any stored selector names. I'm clicking something, and I want to look inside of it for something else.

Again, I don't know what your end goal is with your finds, etc. But hopefully this helps illustrate how to use `.on()` to avoid re-binding event handlers.

[update 2]

The sample is still somewhat convoluted -- it's not clear why the input has to be added dynamically, or why you don't just reverse the order of adding and then calling the plugin (it would then work!).

There is also too much of a reliance on element IDs. For something to be re-usable in a worthwhile way, you're better off using classes. Here's an update to your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/f6QSY/4/

The triggers now have a class "trigger" (the ID is never used now).

the JS part:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    // this is #wrapper because that's the selector that calls it in this sample
    this.on("click", ".trigger", function() {
        var $this = $(this); // this is now the element that was clicked
        var $input = $this.siblings('input'); // the first sibling input of a trigger
        $input.val('set from ' + $this.attr('id'));
        return false;
    });
}

$("#wrapper").append("<input type='text' id='newInput'>");
$("#wrapper").myPlugin();
```

Comment: added code example to show what I'm trying to do - really a custom plugin, which makes it a little trickier (not sure if dereferencing the original selector is safe)

Comment: Thanks, you inspired me to do my first jsfiddle to paint a clearer picture of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: testing in jsPerf shows very little performance benefit from binding to closest non-destroyed DOM node and just the document itself. When an UI starts becoming a bear to micro-manage, I have thrown in the towel and done binding with the document as the listener with no grave side-effects thus far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version of jQuery 1.7+ then you can use `on` because `live` is depricated. However you can still use `delegate`.

Both `on` and `delegate` take advantage of event bubbling mechanism so will work for dynamically created elements.

If you have large number of elements to attach events to then I would suggest you to go for `on` or `delegate` because the event is attached to parent container or `document` and not for all the elements individually. And also if you add or remove the elements inside the container you don't have to worry about. This will give you better performance.

`$(selector).parents(selector2).find(selector3).live(...)` can be replaced using `on` as

```
$(selector2).on('eventType', selector3, function(){...})
```

You can also use `document` as the root element to attach event to if there is not parent container.

```
$(document).on('eventType', selector3, function(){...})
```

Using `delegate`

```
$(document).delegate(selector3, 'eventType', function(){...})
```

Reference: **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Comment: added code example to show what I'm trying to do - really a custom plugin, which makes it a little trickier (not sure if dereferencing the original selector is safe)

Comment: `this.selector` will be null or empty if I use dom element instead of useing a selector. Something like `$(document.getElementById('someid'))` or `$(someDomElement)`.

Comment: Where is the code for original element to remove from the page?

Comment: If the original element does not exist then on what element the plugin will take action?

Comment: In the plugin function, `this` is a jQuery object, so my question is really whether it's safe to call `this.selector` in that context. 
I haven't shown the code that replaces the elements but the assumption is that I'm calling `$(selector).myPlugin()`, and the elements referenced by `$(selector)` are being refreshed by AJAX.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, it is not necessary `this.selector` will always have value. E.g. If I select element by passing dom element `$(someDomElement)`, `this.selector` will be empty in this case.

Comment: If the elements are refreshed by AJAX then you should call initialize the plugin again instead of doing this hack.